# How can I make C-p an Emacs prefix key for Devel::PerlySense?

Tags: perl, emacs

I just installed [Devel::PerlySense](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Devel-PerlySense) 0.0180.

I have put the following in my .emacs file:

```
 ; PerlySense
 (load "~/perly-sense")

 (global-unset-key "\C-p")

 (global-set-key (kbd "\C-p \C-d") 'perly-sense-smart-docs-at-point)

 (global-set-key (kbd "\C-p \C-g") 'perly-sense-smart-go-to-at-point)
```

But, now whenever I try to load a Perl file in emacs, I get the following error prior to it getting loaded:

> error "Key sequence C-p m f starts
>   with non-prefix key C-p"

How can I fixed this? I'm new to emacs, so would really appreciate any help in this regard.

#### Update:

The [link submitted by ysth](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Prefix-Keys.html) suggests, doing the following :

```
 (use-local-map (make-sparse-keymap))
     => nil
 (local-set-key "\C-p" ctl-x-map)
     => nil
 (key-binding "\C-p\C-f")
     => find-file

 (key-binding "\C-p6")
     => nil
```

Now, do i need to add this to my .emacs file to create the keymap?

When i add the above code to .emacs and start emacs the error i get is :

**void-variable =>**

What can be the problem here ?

Comment: the => lines are not meant to be written, they are the result you get from evaluating the line above them. When emacs sees => it thinks it's a variable name and tries to evaluate it but it doesn't exist, hence the void-variable error.

Answer (score 31):

The explicit answer to your question is this:

```
(define-prefix-command 'perly-sense-map)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-p") 'perly-sense-map)
(define-key perly-sense-map (kbd "C-d") 'perly-sense-smart-docs-at-point)
(define-key perly-sense-map (kbd "C-g") 'perly-sense-smart-go-to-at-point)
```

For more information as to what's being done, check out documentation for

- [`define-prefix-command`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Keys.html)
- [`keymaps`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Keymaps.html#Keymaps)
- [`kbd`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Sequences.html#index-kbd-1380)

In the original post, you mixed using `kbd` and the older "\C-p" notation.  You can read [this large tutorial discussing keybindings](http://www.nongnu.org/emacs-tiny-tools/keybindings/), which has tons of information (more than what you probably need).  I find the `kbd` usage to be the easiest, you just pass it the string that you'd see when you do help on a key (<kbd>C-h k</kbd>).

Answer (score 5):

Emacs, by default, only allows certain keys to be prefixes (the start of multi-key commands).  See http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Prefix-Keys.html
You need to create a keymap and bind it to C-p.