# emacs error: Key sequence M-x g starts with non-prefix key M-x

Tags: emacs

I have the following code in `.emacs`: `(global-set-key (kbd "M-x g") 'gnus)` to start Gnus with the keybinding `M-x g`. I obtain: `error: Key sequence M-x g starts with non-prefix key M-x`. How can I define keybindings starting with `M-x`? Is this a bad thing to do and should be avoided? I find it more intuitive since the "long version" is `M-x gnus`. Defining it as `C-c g` for example is no problem but then you start Gnus with `C-c g` and, for example, R via `M-x R` which is not very intuitive (in contrast to starting both via `M-x + 1 letter`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The key <kbd>M-x</kbd> is already bound to the command `execute-extended-command`, which then asks you to provide the name of a command to execute (in you case: `gnus`).

Since `R` is a command only one-character long, it looks like <kbd>M-x R</kbd> is a key sequence, but it's not: it's <kbd>M-x</kbd> followed by entering `R` in the minibuffer and you have to hit <kbd>RET</kbd> to validate your input.

In short:

- you can not set key sequences beginning with <kbd>M-x</kbd> since this key is already bound to a command and is thus not a prefix (unlike <kbd>C-c</kbd>, which does nothing but wait for you to type another key, but should be reserved for bindings specific to the current modes).
- the standard way to do things would be to continue starting gnus using <kbd>M-x gnus</kbd> or to rebind it to an entirely different key if you need to be very quick (you could for example use one of the <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> keys)
- if you really want to have a <kbd>M-x + letter</kbd> binding, you can define a one-letter alias to the command `gnus`, like this:

```lisp
    (defalias 'g 'gnus)
```

Comment: The fourth option would be to clear M-x and make it a prefix key: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024374/how-can-i-make-c-p-an-emacs-prefix-key-for-develperlysense (However, M-x is such a core emacs key that in this case it's probably a bad idea.)