# 3 consecutive key bindings in evil normal mode

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, evil-mode

Nowadays I'm using evil-mode in Emacs.
One of my problem is,
I'm not able to define 3 consecutive key bindings.
If I set like this,

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "crh") 'my-own-function)
```

then,
it shows this error message.

```
Key sequence c r h starts with non-prefix key c
```

Do you know how to overcome this situation? Or is it impossible??

Answer (score 1):

If you use `general` package you can look into `general-nmap`

```
(general-nmap
  "crh" 'your-own-function)
```

About the non-prefix error take a look at

[emacs error: Key sequence M-x g starts with non-prefix key M-x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462111/emacs-error-key-sequence-m-x-g-starts-with-non-prefix-key-m-x)